# grep “+” operator does not work

Tags: regex, linux, grep

File content (text.txt)

```
test aNd###liKe test
```

Example 1, **working**

```
grep -i "and...like" test.txt
```

Example 2, **not working**

```
grep -i "and.+like" test.txt
```

Operator `+` just needs at least one match or more, but why is example 2  not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `+` sign:

```
grep -i "and.\+like" test.txt
```

The unescaped dot `.` already matches every character